# Rails using global constants in environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to access global constants that I define in environment.rb from my controller. I don't think I'm doing it right because they end up being uninitialized in my controller. What would be the correct way of doing so? Thank you.

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Apis::Application.initialize!

KEY_1 = "aghtbjki"
SHARED_SECRET_1 = "plkjuvfe"
KEY_2 = "ljfebjyf"
```

If I'm trying to use KEY_1 in my controller for example, how should I do it?

Comment: Please show us how you are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I don't like putting things in environment.rb and put instead in initializers/my_initializers.rb like:

```
KEY_1 = "aghtbjki"
```

putting it environment.rb seems wrong

Comment: and i can just use it as KEY_1 in my controller?

Comment: Should be able to - try it out

Comment: How to use this "constant" in view?? <%= KEY_1 %>. does not seems to work for me.

Comment: the object has to be global, so it should be $KEY_1 = "aghtbjki" and <%= $KEY_1 %>